# Can I use image hyperlink from the model content to show in my poster image in django templates?

Tags: django, django-templates

OK so this might sound a bit weird.  so im using ckeditor for my content field. So I want to for example run a loop in my template in my content instance. And find "<img" and if its found I wanna check if there is a "/>" so upon finding those I wanna grab the link from that image tag and add that link to my templates poster image
in this line -

```
<img src="{% static 'app/images/movie-poster.jpg' %}" width="100px" />
```

So basically when a user posts if that posts body contains any image then the first image will be added as the poster. So the default poster wont show. Is it possible to do that from template? Sorry im a noob and thats just some solution I thought of and looking for some code logic here. If its posssible then how can i do that ?

I have a model which is this -

```
class List(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    genre = models.ManyToManyField('Genre')
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,blank=True, null=True)
    posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content = RichTextField(null=True,default=' ')
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10,default="Movie")
    spoiler_choices = [(False, 'No'),(True, 'Yes')]
    spoiler = models.BooleanField(default=False,null=True, choices = spoiler_choices)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length= 300,null=True, blank = True, unique=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title}|{self.creator}'
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title + str(self.posted))
        super(List,self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

my template -

```
{% for film in query %}
      <div class="elements">
        <div class="thumb">
          <img src="{% static 'app/images/movie-poster.jpg' %}" width="100px" />
        </div>
        {% if film.spoiler == True %}
          <div class="spoiler"><img src="{% static 'app/images/spoilerr.png' %}" width="100px" /></div>
        {% endif %}
        <div class="Title">
          <a href="{% url 'app:list_detail' film.slug %}"><h4 class="tit">{{film.title}}</h4></a>
          {% if user.id == film.creator.id %}
          <a href="{% url 'app:delete_movie' film.slug %}"><img src ="{% static 'app/images/delete.png' %}"></a>
          <a href="{% url 'app:update_list' film.slug %}"><img src ="{% static 'app/images/edit.png' %}"></a>
          {% else %}
          <img src ="{% static 'app/images/delete-dis.png' %}">
          <img src ="{% static 'app/images/edit-dis.png' %}">
          {% endif %}
        </div>
```

Comment: Do you need to copy the picture to any special location or is the user entered path public and stays valid?

Comment: Users entered path stays valid. Basically its just images from web. Like they go on web search and copy that images address and pastes that link.